# Problems with displaying nodes and lines in the graph of Echarts

Tags: javascript, echarts

I wrote a demo of the topology using the Echarts graph.
However, I had some problems setting up coordinateSystem as a parameter. If I set coordinateSystem to cartesian2d, nodes and lines cannot be displayed. When I comment out this setting, nodes and lines appear normally. Here is the JS code:

```
var dom = document.getElementById('chart-container');
var myChart = echarts.init(dom, null, {
  renderer: 'canvas',
  useDirtyRect: false
});

var app = {};

var option;

option = {
  title: {
    text: 'Basic Graph'
  },
  tooltip: {},
  xAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 400,
    type: 'value',
    axisLine: { onZero: false },
    show: true
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 200,
    type: 'value',
    axisLine: { onZero: false },
    show: true
  },
  series: [{
    type: 'graph',
    coordinateSystem: 'cartesian2d',
    layout: 'none',
    symbolSize: 50,
    roam: true,
    label: {
      show: true
    },
    edgeSymbol: ['circle', 'arrow'],
    edgeSymbolSize: [4, 10],
    data: [{
      name: 'A',
      symbol: 'rect',
      symbolSize: [50, 30],
      x: 100,
      y: 100
    }, {
      name: 'B',
      symbol: 'circle',
      symbolSize: 40,
      x: 300,
      y: 100
    }],
    links: [{
      source: 'A',
      target: 'B'
    }],
    lineStyle: {
      opacity: 0.9,
      width: 2,
      curveness: 0
    },
    draggable: true
  }]
};

if (option && typeof option === 'object') {
  myChart.setOption(option);
}

window.addEventListener('resize', myChart.resize);
```

Comment: If you define `coordinateSystem`, the coordinates are taken from the `value` property of your `data`  [example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/610w9vr7/)